# Graphing a continuous bar plot with different colors/width

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am working on a relatively large dataset (5000 rows) in pandas and would like to draw a bar plot, but continuous and with different colors [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJq7.png).

For every depth data there will be a value of SBT.

Initially, I thought to generate a bar for each depth, but due to the amount of data, the graph does not display it very well and it takes a really long time to load.

In the meantime, I generated a plot of the data, but with lines.

I added the code and the picture of this plot below [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Lha.png).

```
fig, SBTcla = plt.subplots()
SBTcla.plot(SBT,datos['Depth (m)'], color='black',label='SBT')
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.grid(color='grey', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.title('SBT');
plt.xlabel('SBT');
plt.ylabel('Profundidad (mts)');
plt.gca().invert_yaxis();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your graph consists of a lot of points with no information. Consecutive rows which contain the same SBT could we eliminated. Grouping by consecutive rows with equal content can be done by a shift and cummulative sum. The boolean expression looks for steps from one region to the next. If it is a step it returns true and the sum increases by one.

```
x = datos.groupby((datos['SBT'].shift() != datos['SBT']).cumsum())
```

Each group can be plotted on its own, with a filled style